# Access python member from object without dict

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

This is a small piece of an application I'm having some issues with at the moment.

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         print(row['first_name'], row['cat'])
         print(row[1])
```

The application section runs fine with no issues, But I wanted to access each value from 'row' by means of the ith element or through a numerical value.

However, this doesn't seem to function as expected.

Is there a specific way I should be doing this to access member items without having to directly call their column name.

Help and clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `DictReader()`, if all you want is a list of lists then use `csv.reader()`

Comment: I've assumed below that you want to use both keys and indices, but if you *only* want the index @Jkdc is correct, just use `reader`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Great insight and helped me out allot.

Comment: It's a little more advanced, but you can also use `csv.reader()` and convert each row into a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple). The advantage of doing that is that it would allow you to reference each row's contents by both integer indices OR as attributes. By the latter I mean something like this: `row.first_name` and `row.cat`. A possible downside it that, unlike a dictionary, the contents of a tuple can't be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `csv` module gives you two broad ways of accessing data from each line of the file:

1. By index, using [`reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader); or
2. By key, using [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

However, note that a `DictReader` instance has a `fieldnames` attribute, which is *"a sequence whose elements are associated with the fields of the input data in order"*, so to convert from index to key you could use:

```
row[reader.fieldnames[1]]
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the clarification and on point answer!